# does a swagger page string parameter require surrounding quotes?

Tags: rest, web-services, api, swagger

I'm currently testing an API through its swagger page. The service takes 3 string parameters. Does a swagger page string parameter require surrounding quotes? I'm getting a 401 from the underlying service and I'm wondering if it has to do with innappropriately quoted or non-quoted strings.

Comment: Well I tried one test with surrounding quotes around all string params, and then another test without surrounding quotes around any string params.  This first test failed and the second test passed so I'm going to assume that surrounding quotes should never be used around string parameters on a swagger page

Comment: By "swagger page", do you mean [Swagger UI](http://petstore.swagger.io)?

Comment: @Helen, yes.  is that not commonly referred to as the "swagger page" for an api?